# Simple Binary Search Tree Non recursive Add function

Tags: c++, insert, iteration, binary-search-tree

I am trying to write a BST() that would take in strings as nodes without using recursion. here is the add function of my code, can you please review  and see if it is easy to understand/follow and point out mistakes. I am new to programming and would appreciate any feedback.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stack>
#include <queue>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;


int main() {
class BST {

private:
    struct Node {
        string value;
        Node* left;
        Node* right;
    };

    Node* root;

public:

BST()
 {
 root = NULL;
 }

~BST()
{
    stack<Node*> nodes;
    nodes.push( root);
    while( ! nodes.empty())
    {
        Node* topNode = nodes.top();
        nodes.pop();
        if ( topNode->left )
            nodes.push(topNode->left);
        if ( topNode->right )
            nodes.push(topNode->right);
        delete topNode;
      }
   }
Node* GetNewNode(string data){
    Node* newNode = new Node();
    newNode->value=data;
    newNode->left = newNode->right = NULL;
    return root;
 }

Node* Insert(Node* rootPtr,string data){
    if(rootPtr == NULL){
    rootPtr = GetNewNode(data);
        return rootPtr;
    }
    else if(data<= rootPtr->value){
        rootPtr->left = Insert(rootPtr->left,data);
    }
    else {
        rootPtr->right = Insert(rootPtr->right,data);
    }
    return rootPtr;
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: Could you please indent your code properly, it's hard to read as is.

Comment: Please provide code that compiles.

Comment: Hello , the code did compile when i tried compiling it last time

Comment: You said in your question that you want to do it "without using recursion," yet you are clearly using recursion in the Insert function (by calling Insert() inside of Insert()). Can you explain?

Answer (score 0):

1 - In the insert function:

```
        while (root != NULL) { // this shouldn't be root, the root isn't the node that traverse your tree, this has to be current
            .....
        }
```

2- you never add your new node, you just keep looping till you reach a null.
You should traverse your tree till u find the right position to insert your node then add the new node, something like:

```
current = root;
prev = current;
        while (current!= NULL) {
            prev = current;
            if (current->value.compare(word) < 0)
                current = current->left;
            else
                current = current->right;
        }
//here your new node should be on the left or the right of the prev node
```

3 - in "GetNewNode" return the new node not the root

4 - your delete function is a mess, u shall think about it again and re-implement it.

Finally I strongly recommend you to check and understand a ready made implementation from the web then try to write your BST again.